# Yield inside a lamba used by array_* functions

Tags: php, yield

Lets assume I have the following code:

```
function someFunc(){
    // some other logic goes here
    $return = [];

    array_walk_recursive($matches, function($value, $key) use (&$return){
      $return[] = $value;
    });

    return $return;
}
```

Normally this is all fine and dandy. Basically what's happening is `$matches` is being flattened and then returned.

However I want to apply some other logic to each of the `$key => $value` pairs in matches but the logic I want to apply has no place in the current scope.

Of course the code above works just fine, I could simply use a `foreach` to apply the logic after the function is called, for example:

```
  function someOtherFunc(){
    foreach(someFunc() as $key => $value){
      // do stuff
    }
  }
```

But for arguments sake lets assume that instead of returning inside `someFunc` I'd rather `yield`, so `someFunc` would instead be written as:

```
function someFunc(){
    // some other logic goes here
    array_walk_recursive($matches, function($value, $key){
      yield $value;
    });
}
```

This of course will not work since now the anonymous function is turned into a generator which in turn is used by `array_walk_recursive`(it's actually a mystery why this doesn't throw an error, I expected `array_walk_recursive` to complain), which results in well, nothing being yielded to the caller function since the `yield` is satisfied by the scope of the anonymous function.

Basically what I'm asking, is it possible to `yield` the `$value` to the caller without breaking the current flow or some weird hack-ish code?